# Geohash Module installed but import error

Tags: ipython, geohashing

I am using ipython Jupyter notebook in Windows 10. I have installed Geohash using pip install geohash in cmd. 
When I try to use geohash( import geohash) following error comes:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-840910eb012f> in <module>()
----> 1 import geohash

ImportError: No module named 'geohash'
```

Again check whether geohash installed or not then following message came while I try to reinstall:

```
C:\Users\Himal Acharya>pip install geohash
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): geohash in c:\users\himal acharya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docutils>=0.3 in c:\users\himal acharya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from geohash)
```

Again I uninstall geohash. I manually install geohash from github but same problem occur :
import error

Comment: Can you check `sys.path` inside a notebook?

Comment: I checked in site-package ..it shows..but dnot have idea how to put that module in sys.path in windows

Comment: Is that particular `site-packages` directory in sys.path? It's possible that the notebook is running in another environment, so it sees a different site-packages.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
pip install python-geohash
```

This should fix it.

Comment: install --record /private/var/folders/wn/6f963chj009_0rqllwdyjjn00000gn/T/pip-record-s7c_fi9v/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/wn/6f963chj009_0rqllwdyjjn00000gn/T/pip-install-ptlms8nj/python-geohash/

Comment: it mix things, and make Geohash import python-geohash code. 
it become a nightmare to know which code is executed in your project. I just lost 2 days trying to understand why Geohash.decode were responding strings in a project and numbers in another one. So if you do that, please uninstall Geohash before !

Answer (score 5):

Found another way and it works like charm.

from gd-inm source: https://github.com/vinsci/geohash/issues/4

1. rename the package name to be geohash rather than Geohash
2. change **init**.py to import from .geohash (with a dot in front of the module name) rather than from geohash

> I had the same issue - if you rename the package name to be geohash
>   rather than Geohash and then change **init**.py to import from
>   .geohash (with a dot in front of the module name) rather than from
>   geohash, the package should work for Python 3.5.2.

Comment: there is now geohash2 that does exatcly that so you don't have to touch the code

Answer (score 3):

```
pip uninstall Geohash
pip install geohash2
```

it will install https://github.com/DBarthe/geohash version which is exactly the same as vinsci one but compliant with Python 3 import syntax (DBarthe did what @PoonLany explained in its answer)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with python3 which makes me use "[pygeohash](https://github.com/wdm0006/pygeohash)" instead of geohash.

**Instalation**

```
pip install pygeohash
```

**usage**

```
import pygeohash as pgh

pgh.encode(42.6, -5.6)
# >>> 'ezs42e44yx96'

pgh.encode(42.6, -5.6, precision=5)
# >>> 'ezs42'

pgh.decode('ezs42')
# >>> ('42.6', '-5.6')

pgh.geohash_approximate_distance('bcd3u', 'bc83n')
# >>> 625441
```